# How to load table with symbols in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

How can I load a table with symbols or icons in AngularJs and Bootstrap?
I have a table which uses ng-repeat to load a matrix which has 0, 1 or 2 as values inside. So I want the table to not show zeros, and instead of 1 show red circles and instead of 2 yellow circles.

Here is my table:

```
<div class="vertical-center">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
                <td ng-repeat="cell in row track by $index" ng-click="selectPosition($index)">
                    {{cell}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

Comment: you should write a directive for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.data = [
    [0, 0, 2],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [0, 2, 2]
  ];
  $scope.symbols = [
    '',
    '<div class="circle red"></div>',
    '<div class="circle yellow"></div>'
  ].map($sce.trustAsHtml);
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="vertical-center">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
            <td ng-repeat="cell in row track by $index" 
                ng-bind-html="symbols[cell]" 
                ng-click="selectPosition($index)">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nhxYPj3JpwcOWLDS4e0y?p=preview